# iOS app that mostly uses webkit? Is it allowed in the app store?

Tags: ios, iphone, webkit, native

I am developing a consumer product.

My product is accessable via any web browser for easy setup.

I've come to the conclusion that it would be smart to actually
use a web interface to view any content of the product.

That way I technically don't need to create specific native apps for
Windows, OSX, iOS or Android, but instead the user uses the web browser.

However, I am wondering if it is allowed to create a native iOS app
that uses an native interface to show a list of devices on the network
where the user can select one of the devices, which then shows a WebKit view that simply
presents whatever Safari would present if the user would've visited
the product manually via Safari.

So the native iOS app would be a hybrid of native iOS app for the sole
purpose of giving the user the option to select one of the available devices on the network, and the rest is handled via WebKit.

Is this allowed by Apple?

Comment: I've seen several "apps" that basically wrap a website in them in the AppStore. But Apple works in mysterious ways.

Comment: YES,this is allowed by Apple. I have seen some app just use a webView and all content is wrapped in this webView

Comment: Cool cool. Why don't one of you post an answer so I can accept?

Comment: so did you get accepted your app with these functionalities?